# Android Error - AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)"

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I needed to import a working project from Eclipse to Android Studio 2.1 and got the following message from Gradle Console

Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2330Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72330Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42330Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2330Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugShaders
:app:generateDebugAssets
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\advanchip\StudioProjects\Mobile-ControlledLighting\app\src\main\res\layout\dialog_add_gateway.xml","position":{"startLine":0}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

  > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\advanchip\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 12.676 secs

```
    The codes of the xml file is

<!DOCTYPE LinearLayout [<!ELEMENT LinearLayout (LinearLayout|Spinner|EditText|Button)*><!ATTLIST LinearLayoutandroid:background CDATA #IMPLIEDandroid:gravity CDATA #IMPLIEDandroid:id CDATA #IMPLIEDandroid:layout_height CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:layout_width CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:orientation CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:paddingBottom CDATA #IMPLIEDandroid:paddingLeft CDATA #IMPLIEDandroid:paddingRight CDATA #IMPLIEDandroid:paddingTop CDATA #IMPLIEDxmlns:android CDATA #IMPLIEDxmlns:tools CDATA #IMPLIED><!ELEMENT Spinner (#PCDATA)><!ATTLIST Spinnerandroid:id CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:layout_width CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:layout_height CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:layout_gravity CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:layout_marginTop CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:background CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:maxLines CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:paddingBottom CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:paddingTop CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:textStyle CDATA #REQUIRED><!ELEMENT EditText (#PCDATA)><!ATTLIST EditTextandroid:id CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:layout_width CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:layout_height CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:layout_gravity CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:layout_marginTop CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:background CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:hint CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:maxLines CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:paddingBottom CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:paddingLeft CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:paddingRight CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:paddingTop CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:singleLine CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:textColor CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:textStyle CDATA #REQUIRED><!ELEMENT Button (#PCDATA)><!ATTLIST Buttonandroid:background CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:id CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:layout_gravity CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:layout_height CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:layout_marginTop CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:layout_width CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:text CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:textSize CDATA #REQUIRED>]>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#011f4b"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/add_gateway_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/gatewaySerial"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
            android:background="@drawable/rect_text_edit"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
             />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/gatewayName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
            android:background="@drawable/rect_text_edit"
            android:hint="Gateway Name"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#008bcb"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add_gateway_button"
            android:layout_width="200sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/submit_button_bg"
            android:text="Create Gateway"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dialog_cancel"
            android:layout_width="200sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/submit_button_bg"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The code of the app's build.gradle is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.advanchip.mobile_controlledlighting"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0" 
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
    }
    productFlavors { 
    }
}

dependencies {
    //compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    //compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    //compile "com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+"
    //compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+"
    compile files('libs/commons-lang-2.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-logging-1.1.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/smartconfiglib.jar')
}
```

[The image of Android SDK Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvCmc.png)

```
    The codes of rect_text_edit.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />



</shape>


    The codes of submit_button_bg.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@color/button_pressed" />

    <item android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@color/button_normal" />
</selector>


    Please advise, thanks.
```

Comment: post your submit_button_bg  and rect_text_edit file. and remove the <!DOCTYPE line..

Comment: The codes of submit_button_bg.xml    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        
        <item android:state_pressed="true"
                android:drawable="@color/button_pressed" />
        
        <item android:state_enabled="true"
            android:drawable="@color/button_normal" />
    </selector>

Comment: The codes of rect_text_edit.xml    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />

    

</shape>

Comment: there is error in your drawable xmls: xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">;  remove ; (semicolon). it will solve your error..

Comment: Thanks Ramesh.  I checked that ; was not in my original xml file, it was added accidentally when I pasted the codes.  I just re-pasted the codes in my question area.  This is a working project in Eclipse, something went wrong during the imported process which I need help.

Comment: Ramesh, after I deleted  the <!DOCTYPE line.., it worked very nicely.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: Great.. It was my first comment on your question. You can upvote my comment.

Comment: I don't see the up or down arrows next to the comments and don't know how to upvote yours.  Please advise.

Comment: Okay. I can add answer and you can accept it..

Answer (score -2):

There is line in your XML which is irrelevant remove the following line 
`<!DOCTYPE LinearLayout [<!ELEMENT LinearLayout (LinearLayout|Spinner|EditText|Button)*><!ATTLIST LinearLayoutandroid:background CDATA #IMPLIEDandroid:gravity CDATA #IMPLIEDandroid:id CDATA #IMPLIEDandroid:layout_height CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:layout_width CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:orientation CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:paddingBottom CDATA #IMPLIEDandroid:paddingLeft CDATA #IMPLIEDandroid:paddingRight CDATA #IMPLIEDandroid:paddingTop CDATA #IMPLIEDxmlns:android CDATA #IMPLIEDxmlns:tools CDATA #IMPLIED><!ELEMENT Spinner (#PCDATA)><!ATTLIST Spinnerandroid:id CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:layout_width CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:layout_height CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:layout_gravity CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:layout_marginTop CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:background CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:maxLines CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:paddingBottom CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:paddingTop CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:textStyle CDATA #REQUIRED><!ELEMENT EditText (#PCDATA)><!ATTLIST EditTextandroid:id CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:layout_width CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:layout_height CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:layout_gravity CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:layout_marginTop CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:background CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:hint CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:maxLines CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:paddingBottom CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:paddingLeft CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:paddingRight CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:paddingTop CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:singleLine CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:textColor CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:textStyle CDATA #REQUIRED><!ELEMENT Button (#PCDATA)><!ATTLIST Buttonandroid:background CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:id CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:layout_gravity CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:layout_height CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:layout_marginTop CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:layout_width CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:text CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:textSize CDATA #REQUIRED>]>`